# Getting a 'bad listbox index' error when trying to return a value from cursor selection in tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to return the value from the cursor selection for a listbox with tkinter, but I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rachel/PycharmProjects/Final2100/FE1.py", line 36, in <module>
    entvariable1.set(nations[listbox.get(listbox.curselection())]["cont"])
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2798, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', first)
_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number
```

I can't figure out why since I was using listbox.get(listbox.curselection()) just fine earlier in a similar situation.

```py
import pickle
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
def getDictionary(fileName):
    infile = open(fileName, 'rb')
    nations = pickle.load(infile)
    infile.close()
    return nations
nations = getDictionary("UNdict.dat")



lbnations = StringVar()
listbox = Listbox(window, width = 20, listvariable = lbnations)
listbox.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 4, sticky = NSEW)
lbnations.set(tuple(nations))

label1 = Label(window, text = "Continent:")
label1.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 0, column = 2, sticky = E)
label2 = Label(window, text = "Population:")
label2.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 1, column = 2, sticky = E)
label3 = Label(window, text = "Area (sq. miles):")
label3.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 2, sticky = E)

entvariable1 = StringVar()
entvariable2 = StringVar()
entvariable3 = StringVar()
contentry = Entry(window, state = "readonly", textvariable = entvariable1, width = 13)
contentry.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
popentry = Entry(window, state = "readonly", textvariable = entvariable2, width = 13)
popentry.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
areaentry = Entry(window, state = "readonly", textvariable = entvariable3, width = 13)
areaentry.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

##country = listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
entvariable1.set(nations[listbox.get(listbox.curselection())]["cont"])
entvariable2.set(nations[listbox.get(listbox.curselection())]["popl"])
entvariable3.set(nations[listbox.get(listbox.curselection())]["area"])




window.mainloop()
```

I need the entry boxes to produce the dictionary values in the .dat file, the key being the country name which is what I'm trying to get the value of from the cursor selection in the listbox.

Comment: Error show that you use empty string as selection. Check what you get `print( listbox.curselection() )`

Comment: @furas Yeah it only gave me (), I'm not exactly sure why it isn't returning the cursor selection though, it won't even launch the GUI. I tried making a function for it and binding it to left-click to produce the entry box text but it still didn't want to work.

Comment: It worked when I changed it to a button and assigned the function to it, why won't it work otherwise?

Comment: everything before `mainloop()` is executed at start when window doesn't exists yet and you didn't select anything. When you click button then widgets exists and it can get selection.

Comment: Instead of using a button, a more direct way would be binding to `<<ListboxSelect>>` event which is triggered by `Listbox` selection change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `listbox.curselection()` just a few milliseconds after creating the listbox. Nothing is selected because the user hasn't had a chance and you're not programmatically selecting anything, so your code throws an error.